# Is it possible to populate the fields on the same jsp page?

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have a jsp page which has barcodetype and product as fileds and a scan button to start a custom scanner application. Now in my scanner application i wrote code such that it calls same jsp page but with parameters ?contents=' + arr + '&format=' + typ; where arr and typ change with every scan. 
also i call the jsp like this:
var URL = 'http..../myapp/sample.jsp?contents=' + arr + '&format=' + typ;
   navigator.app.loadUrl(URL, {openExternal : true});

its working fine but it opens a new tab/window in mobile external browser. I want it to fill in the samepage so my app will be single paged. 
Is there a way to work? please let me know. Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this you would need to use javascript. Add an event listener to the form submit, stop the form from submitting and collect the form data.

Then you would pass that data to your service, which may or may not be a server api (use ajax) get the response fill out the remaining form, give the response.

**Javascript**

```
function submit(this){

   var barcode = document.getElementById("barcode")

   //...do something perhaps send the barcode to your server using ajax
   //...then when the server calls back update the UI, HTML on the page. 

   // returning false will stop the form from submitting and changing the page.
   return false;
   }
```

**HTML**

```
<form onsubmit="submit(this)">
      <input type="text" id="barcode" value=""/>
      <input type="submit" value="scan"/>
</form>
```

Comment: If you need to send the barcode to the server, you will need to write an api, webservice to return the response. You will also need to use an xhr ajax call in the submit function to get that response.

Comment: I am calling a native app from a web page(jsp) through custom URI <a href="app://">scan</a> and in the app i wrote on click of submit button, navigator.app.loadUrl(url with query strings, {openExternal : true}); so my problem is its opening the same jsp page but in a new window. i want it to return to the same jsp page from which the app is called. I hope i am clear. I am not using any server as of now to store the values. Thankyou MartinWebb

Comment: what is the url you are using to open can i see it

Comment: The app is using phonegap? or are u running the app in the browser?

Comment: I have a mobile webapp with jsp pages and i need to use camera to scan. so i am using corodva scanner plugin to do that. but i am basically working on worklight. It is basically communication between browser and native app. i am calling app from deatils.jsp and want to return the values from the scan to same details.jsp page

Comment: Well you need a plugin, to do some native work on the app, if you were using phonegap you would just configure this plugin and that will do it https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/LaunchMyApp-PhoneGap-Plugin

Comment: I think this is what you need, i think it will work with worklight https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/blob/master/guides/Cordova%20Custom%20URL%20Scheme%20Handling.md

Comment: I already have that plugin. I dont have any problem with the workflow. everything is working perfect except that returnn call of web page would start a new window. I dont know if there is something in specific i need to change so it doesnt go to a new window? sorry for my ignorance. I am a newbie. Thankyou man

Comment: That plugin if you look at the docs on git, fires an event. that event gives you the url, in that url you grab your barcode, do what you want to do, if the window is opening, their should be a means to stop it from the event, perhaps return false? i will take a look

Comment: Do you have a global function handleOpenURL(url) {
    // TODO: parse the url, and do something 
}

Comment: No. i dont have handleOpenUrl(). let me give you steps: 1) from web app <a href="app://">scan</a>  2) in mobile app, i saved the scan reults to an array in js. var URL = 'http.../details.jsp?contents=' + arr + '&format=' + typ; navigator.app.loadurl(URL,{openExternal:true}); that is all no big functionalities.

Comment: So the docs show you that you need to catch the url in the app. then you get access to it, the instructions indicate to install plugin, add global function handleOpenUrl(url)function{...} and to set-up a url schema on IOS. If you don't follow the steps I would imagine it won't work.

Comment: ok. thanks man. I will work on it.I appreciate your time for us.

Comment: Hold on your going from a webpage - with a link--> fire open an app, scan the code, then what your doing is calling your webpage, and of course it opens a new window, which it will, you can't get back to the webpage from the webapp, that is not possible. You can make the new page appear like it did with all the info on it, but it will be a new page.

Comment: yeah. I felt so silly after this discussion. obviously it opens a new one. Now i need to think of another way to get the scanner results to the same page. I hope there is no good option other than callbackUrl. you think there is anything else?

Comment: When the window opens, in that page show a big scan success, in JS code store the info it might be product data in localStorage. Close the window down. Then on your main page add an event listener to localstorage, that event will fire when the scan page sets the data. When that event fires something was scanned and the data is on localstorage.

Comment: I would do that but it should be user-easy-to-operate thing. also there will be a lot of scans in the real production app. I am looking to just autofill the jsp form/fields on a scan.I dont want a newpage to open and show something and close. if in the case, we add a event listener to read data from the app local storage. why dont we just do it without having to show success page. P.S I donno how exactly what you said works, but now i am gonna learn all those. your info was so helpful.

Comment: Just one last question, is there any way we could close the existing windowthe app has been called from the app's JS code. ?